# Parse a parameter to a case

Tags: .net, parameters, arguments, case

I can't seem to find a solution for this, so I'll just ask it away.

I've got a method that receives a string, interprets it and it gives an answer. If something goes wrong it gives out a default case.

```
private string ProcessCommand(string str)
    {
        string result = "";
        switch (str)
        {
            case "hello":
                result = "Hello!";
                break;
            default:
                result = "Sorry, I do not recognize your command";
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Now I want to make a bit more advanced. For example: I've got a command getSurname + parameter, so the input is `/getSurname Adam` and I want the output to be Sandler. How do I make my code to recognize the proper command with parameter/argument that I'm passing in?

Comment: Can you explain further? "*input is /getSurname Adam and I want the output to be Sandler*". I am not getting this bit

Comment: The call by the operand command to separate the operands and command.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, in other words it's like: `ProcessCommand("getSurname Adam");` and returns a String Sandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the command and the value within the same parameter, delimited by a specific character (`=`, for example).

Then your parameter string would be something like `/getSurname=Adam`.

If you need to pass multiple values to the method, you will need to come up with a scheme for separating them (might be good to html-encode and pass them in like a querystring).

Some example code on how to split on the delimiter (assumes that `str` can contain multiple params separated by spaces):

```
string paramDelimiter = ' '
string[] params = str.Split(paramDelimiter);
string valDelimiter = '=';
foreach (string paramString in params) {
  if (paramString.IsNullOrEmpty()) continue;
  string[] paramAndVal = paramString.Split(valDelimiter);
  string param = paramAndVal[0];
  string val = paramAndVal[1];

  // logic goes here to switch through params and handle them 
  // based on the value that was passed
}
```

Your function code would then be responsible for parsing each parameter into command and value (or command and name/value pairs) and using them as needed.

Comment: If you mean making a separate case like
`case "getSurname+Adam":
  result = "Sandler";`
Then no, because I will have hundreds of these.

Comment: Yes, you could use `+` as a delimiter between command and value instead of `=`. As long as you stick to the convention and handle the case where the delimiter could be part of the value or command.

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko - first split that "getSurname=Adam" on the "=", then match on the "getSurname" bit. Then you can use that second part (here "Adam") as parameter to your getSurname method.

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko I just added some sample code to show how you could derive params and values from the input string

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a Regular Expression or a string.split() to parse your command string into a command and an array of arguments.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vrm7X/1/

Code:

```
$("#btnRun").on("click", function() {
    var commandString = $("#cmd").val(),
        commandArguments = commandString.split(" "),
        command = commandArguments.shift();

    alert("Your command is: " + command);
    for (arg in commandArguments) {
        alert("Argument " + arg + ": " + commandArguments[arg])   
    }
});
```

For extended command-syntax you should use an Regular Expression that parses things like

```
/surname -Name John -Age 33
```

to

```
Command: surname
Argument 'Name': John
Argument 'Age': 33
```

Comment: I see the example works great, but I will need some time to adapt it to my code, as this is a bit complicated for me xD

Comment: OK, just ask if you need further explanation. Which part isn't clear to you? I could provide a full working example with some basic "Command Parser" included.